# Method Not Allowed (GET): /home/ usando Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-templates, django-queryset

Sou novo usando Django e estou tentando acessar minha home e estou tendo erro 405 Method Not Allowed (GET)

Tenho um arquivo post_views.py dentro da pasta blog/views

```
from blog.models import Post


class PostView(generic.View):
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(status=1).order_by("-created_on")
    template_name = "index.html"


class PostDetail(generic.DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = "post_detail.html"
```

O blog/urls.py esta assim

```
from blog import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.PostView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('<slug:slug>/', views.PostDetail.as_view(), name='post_detail'),
]
```

e o djangoblog/urls.py esta assim:

```
"""djangoblog URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.urls import include, path
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  path('blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('home/', include('blog.urls')),
]
```

esse é o log do terminal:

```
Method Not Allowed (GET): /home/
Method Not Allowed: /home/
[10/Nov/2021 19:26:50] "GET /home/ HTTP/1.1" 405 0
```

Answer (score -3):

Opa amigo blza?

O erro esta lá no seu post_views.py
Como se trata de uma lista que sera renderizada vc deve usar a classe generic.ListView e não generic.View :)

Recomendo dar uma olhada na documentção [aqui](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/).

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).